# flask - sqlalchemy - self-referential query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to do query in sqlalchemy to get with self-referential relationship which is filtered on parent and also child level.

```
category_country = Table('category_country', Base.metadata,
    Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('country_id', Integer, ForeignKey('country.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    subcategories = relationship("Category", backref=backref('parent', remote_side=id))
    countries = relationship(Country, secondary = category_country, backref='categories')

class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = "country"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

query

```
category = s.query(Category).join(Category.countries).options(contains_eager(Category.countries)).filter(Country.id == 1).filter(Category.id == category_id).join(Category.countries, aliased=True).join(Category.subcategories, aliased=True).options(contains_eager(Category.countries)).filter(Country.id == 1).first()
```

but it doesn't work. I need to find children which are from country 1 and its parent is category_id and country is also 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely get your model/code on my first read, but the way I would tackle this is by splitting the self-referential join into a **subquery() statement** like this:

```
filter_by_country = (db.session.query(...)
                     .filter(...)
                     .subquery())

final_results = (db.session.query(...)
                 .join(filter_by_country, 
                       db.and_(Category.id == filter_by_country.c.id, ..., ...))
                 .options(...)
                 .filter(...)
                 .etc(...).first())
```

I've found this sort of a pattern can help simplify these type of queries. Hope this helps.